# Type cast string to Int

Tags: swift, typecasting-operator

I am getting string in response, i want to convert it into Int following is my code

```
Int("\(dicOtherData["active_job"])!")!
```

but it will giving fatal error at run time

Comment: The tag *typecasting-operator* is wrong twice. There is no operator involved and the type is not casted.

Answer (score 4):

Never force-unwrap an optional if you cannot be 100 % sure that it contains what you expect. Rather use a pattern like this:

```
if let myString = dicOtherData["active_job"], let myInt = Int(myString) {
    // do something
}
```